# Get gmail contacts from GIDSignIn ios

Tags: oauth, gmail, contacts, gidsignin

I'm trying to get gmail contacts in my app but got confused on how to achieve this. I'm using GIDSignIn and I've read that OAUTH is used within GIDSignIn to grant access. Is there a way to get contacts using GIDSignIn?, I added the scopes for contatcs but how do I make the contacts request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find something?